# NullPointerException unmarshal

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying to unmarshal a xml file. This is the tree of it:

```
<kingdom>
<houses>
<house>
<coatofarms>A running grey direworlf, on an ice-white field</coatofarms>
<id>2</id>
<name>House Stark of Winterfell</name>
<region>The North</region>
<seats>
<seat>Scattered(Formerly Winterfell)</seat>
</seats>
<titles>
<title>King in the North</title>
<title>Lord of Winterfell</title>
<title>Warden of the North</title>
<title>King of the Trident</title>
</titles>
<words>Winter is Comming</words>
</house>
<house>
<coatofarms>A gold lion, on a crimson field(Gules, a lion or)</coatofarms>
<id>229</id>
<name>House Lannister of Casterly Rock</name>
<region>The Westerlands</region>
<seats>
<seat>Castlery Rock</seat>
</seats>
<titles>
<title>King of the Rock(formerly)Lord of Casterly Rock</title>
<title>Shield of Lannisport</title>
<title>Warden of the West</title>
</titles>
<words>Hear me Roar</words>
</house>
</houses>
<king>Robert Baratheon</king>
<location>Westeros</location>
<name>Seven Kingdoms</name>
</kingdom>
```

This is my code that generates the error:

```
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(kingdom.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream( "gotmarsh.xml" );
 

kingdom que = (kingdom) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(inStream)  ;
```

Class that contains house.java

```
package jaxb;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;

/**
 *
 * @author 2dam
 */
public class house {

    public house() {
    }
    
    private int id; 
    private String name; 
    private String region; 
    private String coatOfArms; 
    private String words; 
    private String[] titles; 
    private String[] seats; 
    @XmlElement(name="id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @XmlElement(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @XmlElement(name="region")

    public String getRegion() {
        return region;
    }

    public void setRegion(String region) {
        this.region = region;
    }
    @XmlElement(name="coatofarms")

    public String getCoatOfArms() {
        return coatOfArms;
    }

    public void setCoatOfArms(String coatOfArms) {
        this.coatOfArms = coatOfArms;
    }
    @XmlElement(name="words")

    public String getWords() {
        return words;
    }

    public void setWords(String words) {
        this.words = words;
    }
     @XmlElementWrapper(name="titles")
    @XmlElement(name="title")  
    public String[] getTitles() {
        return titles;
    }

    public void setTitles(String[] titles) {
        this.titles = titles;
    }
  @XmlElementWrapper(name="seats")
    @XmlElement(name="seat")  
    public String[] getSeats() {
        return seats;
    }

    public void setSeats(String[] seats) {
        this.seats = seats;
    }

    public house(int id, String name, String region, String coatOfArms, String words, String[] titles, String[] seats) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.region = region;
        this.coatOfArms = coatOfArms;
        this.words = words;
        this.titles = titles;
        this.seats = seats;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Class that contains kingdom.java

```
package jaxb;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author 2dam
 */
@XmlRootElement
public class kingdom {
    
  private List<house> houses; 
  private String name;
    private String king;
    private String location;

        @XmlElementWrapper(name="houses")
    @XmlElement(name="house")        
    public List<house> getHouses() {
        
        return houses;
        
        
        
    }

    public void setHouses(ArrayList<house> houses) {
        this.houses = houses;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @XmlElement(name="king")
    public String getKing() {
        return king;
    }

    public void setKing(String king) {
        this.king = king;
    }
    @XmlElement(name="location")
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }


    public kingdom(List<house> houses, String name, String king, String location) {
        this.houses = houses;
        this.name = name;
        this.king = king;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public kingdom() {
    }

    
    
}
```

I have tried many solutions but everything leads to nullpointer.

I have read that maybe is the XmlElementWrapper that returns null, but no idea.

If you need more code please ask.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

In my case I changed the list in kingdom.java

private List houses ;
to

private List houses  = new LinkedList() ;